# Pip installs files to the old version of Python (Pip, Pandas, Python, Mac)

Tags: python, pandas, macos, pip

I just started learning about Python (on macOS Mojave). I downloaded the latest version of Python and wanted to download software libraries like pandas.

So firstly I downloaded pip like that: sudo easy_install pip

Then I installed pandas using pip, however pandas location is: Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.24.2)

However, my Pythons location is:
Location of Python 3.8.2:
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3'

Also when I try importing pandas in the python command I get this:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Therefore, it seems that pip has installed pandas to the old version of Python. How can I fix that? Or is that even the problem? Again I am totally new to this and I don't come from a cs background. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: Use virtual environments, or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have both `pip` and `pip3` installed, where the first is used for python `2.7` and the second for python `3.8.2`

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip

Answer (score 0):

You need to add pip to your terminal's commands. In the meantime, you could do this:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Note that that will only work if when you run `python -V`, you get `python 3.8.2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip